# iOS UIImageView scaling image down produces aliased image on iPad 2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I am using UIImageView to display thumbnails of images that can then be selected to be viewed at full size. The UIImageView has its content mode set to aspect fit.

The images are usually scaled down from around 500px x 500px to 100px x 100px. On the retina iPad they display really well while on the iPad2 they are badly aliased until the size gets closer to the native image size.

Examples:

[image: Original Image]

Original Image

[image: Retina iPad 100x100]

Retina iPad rendering at 100px x 100px

[image: iPad 2 100x100]

iPad 2 rendering at 100px x 100px

The difference between iPad 2 and new iPad might just be the screen resolution or could be that the GPU is better equipped to scale images. Either way, the iPad 2 rendering is very poor.

I have tried first reducing the image size by creating a new context, setting the interpolation quality to high and drawing the image into the context. In this case, the image looks fine on both iPads.

Before I continue down the image copy/resize avenue, I wanted to check there wasn't something simpler I was missing. I appreciate that UIImage isn't there to be scaled but I was under the impression UIImageView was there to handle scaling but at the moment it doesn't seem to be doing a good job scaling down. What (if anything) am I missing?

**Update**: Note: The drop shadow on the rendered / resized images is added in code. Disabling this made no difference to the quality of the scaling.

Comment: How are you scaling it down? Programmatically or in IB?

Comment: The UIImageView is created in code and added to a scroll view. UIImageView is created with a frame of size 100 x 100 and the image is assigned with .image = [UIImage imageWithName:@"hat"]

Comment: I believe that UIImageVIew skips anti-aliasing for a too large image probably for a performance reason. 
Probably a 500x500 image can be properly scaled down with anti-aliasing, if the current devices or iOS versions in 2020 are used. But the problem is still happening for over around 1024x1024 images to me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625467/4030065

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Another approach I've tried that does seem to be improving things is to set the minificationFilter:

```
[imageView.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear]
```

The quality is certainly improved and I haven't noticed a performance hit.

Comment: This seems to be working well on an iPad 2 with 3G but not a wifi-only iPad 2, which seems a bit crazy.

Comment: Turns out the difference between the iPads was actually iOS version. Seems iOS 6 does a much better job with trilinear filtering than iOS 5.1

Comment: I find this works *most* of the time, but strangely occasionally fails and renders with the poorer filter just sometimes. Really strange. Could be something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To me, in some cases, this resulted in an  strange added border around the imageview, but only on an iPad2 & iPad3, and _not_ on an iPad Air.....

Comment: Just be aware of the memory implications of using trilinear filtering. See my answer below for a little more info.

Answer (score 10):

Applying a small minification filter bias can help out with this if you don't want to resample the image yourself:

```swift
imageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterTrilinear
imageView.layer.minificationFilterBias = 0.1
```

[image]

The left image has no filtering applied to it. The right image has a 0.1 filter bias.

Note that no explicit rasterization is required.

Playing around with very small values, you can usually come up with a value that smooths out the scaling artifacts just enough, and it's a lot easier than resizing the bitmap yourself. Certainly, you lose detail as the bias increases, so values even less than 0.1 are probably sufficient, though it all depends on the size the image view's frame that's displaying the image.

Just realize that trilinear filtering effectively enables [mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) on the layer, which basically means it generates extra copies of the bitmap at progressively smaller scales. It's a very common technique used in rendering to increase render speed and also reduce scaling aliasing. The tradeoff is that it requires more memory, though the memory usage for successive downsampled bitmaps reduces exponentially.

Another potential advantage to this technique, though I have not tried it myself, is that you can animate `minificationFilterBias`. So if you're going to be scaling an image view down quite a lot as part of an animation, consider also animating the filter bias from `0.0` to whatever small value you've determined is appropriate for the scaled down size.

Finally, as others have noted, if your source image is very large, this technique isn't appropriate if overused, because Core Animation will always keep around the original bitmap. It's better to resize the image then discard the source image instead of using mipmapping in most cases, but for one-offs or cases where your image views are going to be deallocated quickly enough, this is fine.

Answer (score 7):

if you just put the large image in a small imageview it will look real bad.

the solution is to properly resize the image... i'll add an example function that does the trick:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

this function might take some time .. so you might want to save the result to a cache file.

Comment: It's probably worth add some constraints to the height and width so you don't distort the image. Other than that this the best solution to the problem.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. I now have to learn how to cache files though.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not afraid of wasting memory and know what you're doing for a particular case, this works beautifully.

```
myView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
myView.layer.rasterizationScale = 2;
```

The resulting quality is much better than setMinificationFilter.

I am using images that are 256x256 and scaling them to something like 48 px. Obviously a saner solution here would be to downscale the images to the exact destination size.

Comment: This just tells CoreAnimation to keep around rasterized images (images of the view after being rendered) which can help save time compositing (the sublayers of a rasterized layer don't have to be composited on subsequent frames because they've already been flattened into the rasterized image of their superlayer). I can't see this having any impact on the scaled image quality.

Comment: This was just based on my observation. The quality was definitely better. Note that in my case, using lower resolution image sources (closer to the final scale) fixed the issue.  I suspect Apple just forces some lower quality stuff when it gets slow. This component was used in a TableView some it was scaled many times when scrolling.

Comment: This does have a perceived improvement in visual quality, and it's also very useful for getting rid of jagged edges during animation if you're, say, rotating some image or otherwise transforming it. My guess is that UIImageView's way of scaling its rendered output is not the same as how CALayer handles it when rasterization is enabled. After all, when you tell it to rasterize, CALayer has the final say in how it displays the bitmap.

Comment: I've found that a rasterizationScale of 6 is needed, on a 3x screen. I didn't find a need for the trilinear filter that other answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Next helped to me:

```
imageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterTrilinear
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

**Keep an eye on performance** if used in scroll lists.