# iOS UIScrollView Antialiasing

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, antialiasing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS UIImageView scaling image down produces aliased image on iPad 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730384/ios-uiimageview-scaling-image-down-produces-aliased-image-on-ipad-2)

I guess this doesn't bother a lot of people other than me, but on the older phones (3GS and before) if you put a large image in a UIScrollView and then zoom out, the image looks really aliased, i.e. jaggy. On the newer devices with higher resolution screens, it looks fine.

Is there any way to antialias the image?

Bad:

[image]

Good:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can either use a downsampled image for non-retina display devices or apply a core image filter to the existing image. Maybe try a CIGaussianBlur.