# How to shrink UIImageview contents with better interpolation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer

I'm shrinking a UIImageView but it's looks horrible and aliased.
I've tried changing the 'minifactionFilter' property but I don't see any effects.
Is there a special way to implement this? There's not much info in apple's docs.

```
    self.imageView.layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterLinear;
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0;
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I know the layer properties are working as I can see the round corners but interpolation always looks the same.

kCAFilterNearest

[image: kCAFilterNearest]

kCAFilterLinear

[image: kCAFilterLinear]

kCAFilterTriLinear

[image: kCAFilterTrilear]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UIImageView scaling image down produces aliased image on iPad 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730384/ios-uiimageview-scaling-image-down-produces-aliased-image-on-ipad-2)