# Bigger size image in smaller image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

This is more sort of a logical question, everything is working fine.

I have an ImageView and for that I download images from the web server. Our web server keeps the biggest size image and then I am rescaling the images down for required devices. So lets say, if I have an UIImageView with size 200 * 200 and I am downloading image of 400 * 400, I rescale the image to 200 * 200 and then I put it in the imageview, I tried putting 400 by 400 image in 200 by 200 image view and it looks fine to me (no pixelation). The way I implemented the downscaling is

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
```

within the image context. Now I feel like apple might be doing this anyway because it is rescaling my image to fit in the image view, so is it really required? Or should I just put high resolution images directly in the image view?

Suggestions required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine to just assign a 400x400 UIImage to a 200x200 UIImageView. CoreAnimation will deal with the image scaling underneath.

***Image Quality***

If you want to experiment with different image scaling qualities, you can set the [`minificationFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/minificationFilter) on the UIImageView's layer. The default is `kCAFilterLinear`, which I think would be fine for your usage. Multiple pixels from the 400x400 image will be selected and linearly blended together to get the 200x200 image pixel color. `kCAFilterNearest` will get you better performance at the cost of image quality (a single pixel from the 400x400 image is selected to get the color for the 200x200 image pixel).

You could experiment using `kCAFilterTrilinear` instead, which should get you better image quality at the cost of some performance. The documentation doesn't make it clear which devices this will actually have an affect, although [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730384/ios-uiimageview-scaling-image-down-produces-aliased-image-on-ipad-2) had success using it on an iPad 2 which makes me think it may be supported on all devices now. The documentation also notes your image may need to be of dimensions of a power of 2 for this to have affect.

***Performance***

You could scale the image down from 200x200 perhaps as a performance optimization to save memory and CoreAnimation render time (including the image scaling), but I wouldn't do that unless you have reason to think your app's performance would actually benefit from this.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your reply. Performance is not an issue for me. I did this initially so I dont have pixelation problem. Its now after implementation, I was trying to understand whether this manual downscaling is actually required. Even I feel like it is redundant. In your experience, have you ever observed any pixelation issue with default CoreAnimation downscaling (keeping the aspect ratio same) ?

Comment: I've always been happy with the scaling Core Animation's been doing. I think the dimensions you're using (halving each dimension) should mean the image scaling is pretty good for you. I've updated my answer with a bit more info which might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, this was really helpful. I didn't know about this minificationFilter previously. Thanks a lot again :)