# iOS - jagged edges on text and image. Why? and how to fix?

Tags: ios, image, text, antialiasing

Why are there jagged edges on some of the texts and images in the app i am developping?

I have tried to go through the frames, and i have not used a division to set a frame (so the 1.134234 is not an issue), and I have tried different antialiasing methods.

Does anybody have an idea?

See attached for an example.

EDIT:
The images become jagged, when downscaled. So either resize them to fit the size directly in the actual file, OR via code as suggested in other StackOverflow questions.
Now trying to figure out how to fix the text also! :)

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

Answer will posted tomorrow (after 24 hours).

1) Image problem: Make sure the actual image size you are using is close to the size you are actually using it... (Feks 100 points with an image at @1x that is 100, @2x that is 200, and @3x that is 300, where 100,200, and 300 are the actual image file pixels). Or resize using code in the correct way to match.
When iOS is downscaling (as well as upscaling) an image, the pixels get disorted.
The problem in my case was using a too big an image.

2) As to the button, I don't know exactly why, but it got solved using attributedText for the title instead of the usual text. Method used is:
     [button setAttributedTitle: forState:];

[image: Jagged edges]

Comment: Depends entirely on how you’re doing your drawing. Can you supply some code?

Comment: basically im not drawing anything? the "-400" is a simple button... and the same is the pie chart. A simple button. both in same embed uiview that has a border and corner radius. Thats basically it.

Comment: Are you supplying the required images at the needed resolution? Do you have the `@2x` and `@3x` versions for your images?

Comment: Yes I am ... see edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it :D

1) Image problem: Make sure the actual image size you are using is close to the size you are actually using it... (Feks 100 points with an image at @1x that is 100, @2x that is 200, and @3x that is 300, where 100,200, and 300 are the actual image file pixels). Or resize using code in the correct way to match.
When iOS is downscaling (as well as upscaling) an image, the pixels get disorted.
The problem in my case was using a too big an image.

2) As to the button, I don't know exactly why, but it got solved using attributedText for the title instead of the usual text. Method used is:
[button setAttributedTitle: forState:];

Comment: This answer helped me. I had the same problem when using UIImageView in a storyboard. The image was jagged or aliased. The cause was that a too large image like 1024x1024 or 2048x2048 was resized. I guess the problem is nothing to do with \@1x, \@x2, or \@x3. We don't need @1x, \@x2, or \@x3 versions to scale. UIImageView probably doesn't support anti-aliased scaling for a too large image for probably a performance reason.